# Prevent automatic download of attachments

Tags: outlook-2010

We have had a PDF containing a virus get through our email filter, the anti-virus on the email filter didn't detect the virus however the anti-virus on the desktop did detect the virus and promptly dealt with it.

When de-briefing the user they have reported that they didn't open the attachment, they determined it was spam and when they clicked on the email do delete it the virus was detected.

I haven't been able to determine whether Outlook does download an attachment when you click on it, the user has reading pane enabled.

Can anyone advise if Outlook is downloading attachments on opening an email and whether it can be disabled?

We are not wanting to disable attachments, just making it so that the attachment is only downloaded when the attachment is actually opened by the user.

Comment: Yeah we've got those extensions all blocked in the email filter and can only be released with IT intervention, the same for encrypted emails.  I guess, given the lack of any evidence, that the workstation AV was probably scanning the email and attachments as part of the on-access scan.

Comment: Would it be naive to think that not running in cached mode would stop attachments getting downloaded until you open them?